# dismiss divs and when all are dismissed the wrapper is auto dismiss

Tags: javascript, jquery, dismiss

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1">
     <p>Content Here</p>
     <button type="button" class="close">Close Box1</button>
  </div>

  <div class="box2">
     <p>Content Here</p>
     <button type="button" class="close">Close Box2</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box3">

     <p>Content Here</p>
     <button type="button" class="close">Close Box3</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/KeChx

i tried using twitter bootstrap alert dismiss but it only close the 1st outer div tag,
for example the close button is inside box1 and i want to close the outer div.wrapper.

what i'm after for is to be able to close/dismissed the box1,box2,box3 individually and once all of them are close/dismissed the div.wrapper will be automatically be dismissed too..

any ideas how can i get this?

i tried searching here but most that i found is a pop-up with a close function, which isn't what i need since these boxes doesn't need to pop-up..

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Fiddle added above. Update it with your CSS if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to get `data-dismiss` working on a non-modal element, but it's just as easy to do your own jQuery function:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/KeChx/6

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('div').slideUp();
});
```

In this case there's no reason to dismiss the parent element once it's empty, but you certainly could like this:

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('div').slideUp();

    if (! $('.wrapper > div') ) {
        $('.wrapper').hide();
    }
});
```

Here's an example of the above in action. I've set it to close the parent `.wrapper` if the child count gets below 2 for clarity.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/KeChx/8

```
function closeEmptyWrapper() {
    var divCt = $('.wrapper').find('div').not(':hidden').size();

    if (divCt < 2) {
        $('.wrapper').fadeOut();
    }
}

$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).parent('div').slideUp('', closeEmptyWrapper);
});
```

Comment: Thanks isherwood! exactly what i needed!

one question, i tried this on my local-drive with bootstrap.min.js v3.1.1 and i move the .close button 2 div deeper inside the div.box.. due to content layouting purpose.. would it cause the function not to work? i tried it and its not working...

and the div.box is also 2 div tags deep inside the div.wrapper

its now
div.wrapper
-> div.content 
   -> div.col10 
      -> div.box 
          -> div.row 
             -> div.col8 
                -> button.close

Comment: You'd have to change the selectors to match your HTML.

Comment: can you help me out with this - > http://jsfiddle.net/KeChx/9/
its the actual codes that i have.. i already matched the selectors to my HTML but still can't get things to work..

Thanks in advance Isherwood

Comment: Here's a cleaner fiddle. Notice that Bootstrap JS and CSS are loaded in the External Resources sidebar section. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nH6z9 Please indicate which element you want to click, and which you want to close onclick.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nH6z9/2/ Awesome! but is it possible to have the wrapper to remain if there is still another box that is inside the Show link, its a collapse.. the box under the collapse needs to be close too before the whole div.bid-option disappears.

Comment: Note that I've added an ID called `box_wrapper` to enable easier selection. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/nH6z9/4

Comment: thanks Isher, your really a life saver!!! btw i have a client in USA who's looking for a php developer paid video streaming site, i'm wondering if you are interested? its quiet hard to find a good programmer that can be trusted with long project.. anyway i really really appreciate all your patience and help here.. you have a awesome day Isher, god bless you :)

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but I'm employed full time and also do more side work than I probably should. I appreciate the thought, though. May Poseidon's blessings be upon you.